# How to apply styling on fly when using Highlight.js plugin?

Tags: javascript, html, css, syntax-highlighting

I'm working on some code where I need to trigger event on fly and apply the highlight styling. For some reason the styling is not getting applied.

https://jsfiddle.net/qm9rgh0u/

```js
hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();

var content_div = document.getElementById("edit");

content_div.addEventListener("keypress", function() {
  hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();

})
```

```css
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.11.0/styles/default.min.css');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.11.0/highlight.min.js"></script>

<div id="edit" contenteditable="true">
  <pre>
<code>
    var i = 0,
        colors = ["red","blue","green"];
    var content = document.getElementById("text");
    function appendFunction(e,id){

      var new_span = document.createElement("span");
      new_span.style.color = colors[i];
      new_span.textContent = id.textContent;
      id.append(new_span);
      // var new_span = "<span style=color:'+colors[i]+'>"+id.textContent+"</span>";
      // var
      // id.append(new_span);
    }



      var id = document.getElementById("text");
      id.addEventListener("keyup", function(event){
        appendFunction(event,id);
      })



</code>
</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation? https://highlightjs.org/usage/

Comment: @FelixKling They have not mentioned anything about doing on fly.

Comment: No? What about the `Custom Initialization` part? Or about https://highlightjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html .

Comment: @FelixKling The api has not talked about attaching event and styling it.

Comment: You are right, the documentation doesn't show how to attach event handlers, but that's not a concern of the library. You also already seem to know how to bind event handlers. What the documentation shows is which methods exist, what input they expect and what their return value is. From the first link I posted: `hljs.highlightBlock(block);`. However, if you want to highlight code as it is being written, things might be more complicated and you might want to look into existing editor solutions.

Comment: @FelixKling [http://codepen.io/kazzkiq/pen/xGXaKR/](http://codepen.io/kazzkiq/pen/xGXaKR/) This JS does solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I added `id="codeblock"` to your html `<code>` tag

also with updated js, I changed keypress to blur so you can update the code and when you lose focus you get the updated style:

```
hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();

var content_div = document.getElementById("edit");
content_div.addEventListener("blur", function() {
  hljs.highlightBlock(document.getElementById("codeblock"));
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/r2a56w9b/

Comment: I changed the event to be "keyup" and triggering the highlight function on keycode 32. When I do this the cursor is starting from the 0th index of the line. Do you know what the problem would be?

Comment: @SharathV every time you update the style you lose the focus, therefore you started at begin of the line, not sure about the fix, that's why I suggest you use blur

Comment: @SharathV: Changing the content of the element (which is what you do when you apply highlighting) will affect the cursor position. That's why I suggested to use existing solutions, unless you want to solve the cursor problem yourself of course.

Comment: @SharathV I might have a solution, wait a sec

Comment: @FelixKling Is it possible to apply that styling for normal text using this [http://codepen.io/kazzkiq/pen/xGXaKR/](http://codepen.io/kazzkiq/pen/xGXaKR/) editor?  I have tried using normal javascript but the way too much work around. Here is the fiddle for 4 words case : [https://jsfiddle.net/a8kk4q10/](https://jsfiddle.net/a8kk4q10/).

Comment: @DanielH [https://jsfiddle.net/a8kk4q10/](https://jsfiddle.net/a8kk4q10/) I've tried it this way for applying styling to normal text. For the syntax highlighting I found this JS [http://codepen.io/kazzkiq/pen/xGXaKR/ ] (http://codepen.io/kazzkiq/pen/xGXaKR/ ).

Comment: @SharathV it is not kind tricky since the lib you are using for highlights I'm not sure how it works, need more time to really figure it out